# How to update Vector2 state without breaking encapsulation in LibGdx?

Tags: java, android, oop, libgdx

Here are the docs for  the Vector2 class which is supposed to encapsulate a 2D vector. 
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html

Based on the demonstration here and the api, is there a way of setting the fields of Vector2 without accessing them directly, after all "Encapsulation refers to the state of objects - objects encapsulate their state and hide it from the outside". - [Encapsulation vs Abstraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960918/how-encapsulation-is-different-from-abstraction-as-a-object-oriented-concept-in)
 Is there a reason why this class doesn't have any getters and setters for x and y?

Here's how the author of the demo set the x and y fields. 
Demo - http://www.kilobolt.com/day-5-the-flight-of-the-dead---adding-the-bird.html

```
 if (velocity.y > 200) {
        velocity.y = 200;
}
 and 
   public void onClick() {
    velocity.y = -140;
}
```

which I think violates encapsulation in OO design. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What about set(float x, float y)?

Comment: But you have some way of retrieving the x and y without breaking encapsulation

Comment: You mean getters? No, there isn't any getter in Vector2 class.

Comment: Yeah I think they should have them. It can't hurt can it?

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html Here you go. As you can see there is no getters. But libgdx is open source so you are free to add them.

Comment: do you add via commit to github repository?

Comment: If you want to change source code of libgdx, search here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx

Comment: Yeah I don't think that I'm that good enough with github(not at all) and libgdx yet.  I come back to this in the future though.

Comment: Nothing bad in velocity.x instead of velocity.getX().

Comment: A Vector2 is a simple object with only two variables. There is no way to break the object by directly accessing and modifying its elements because there are no necessary side effects of changing either value. In C++, it would be a struct.

Comment: In this case the benefits of encapsulation are not really justified, because the elements are so frequently accessed and they're being used in a game engine, where performance is critical. The only benefit I can see is convenience if you are used to typing `get`. If you submit a pull request, I don't think they will accept a change that reduces visibility of `x` and `y`. Plus, it would break just about every class in every game made by anyone. :) In my opinion, there should not be getters and setters sitting along side a public variable, because it might be a source of confusion.

Comment: I mean how would making the fields private having setters/getters affect performance?

Comment: They don't change performance, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931546/java-getter-and-setter-faster-than-direct-access